# tufte handouts hyperref problem on arxiv

Tags: hyperref, tufte, arxiv, option-clash

I'm uploading a very simple [tufte handout](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/master/sample-handout.tex) based paper to arxiv and I'm getting an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.
```

but I am not loading hyperref anywhere. I'm only loading amsmath, babel, graphicx, polski (the polish latex package), booktabs, untis and multicol packages. I'm not chaning any hyperref options explicitly. Is there a general problem with arxiv supporting the tufte class?

Comment: A package can also be loaded by other packages or the class. In this case, `hyperref` is loaded by the class `tufte-handout` with options `unicode, hyperfootnotes=false`. If a package is loaded twice, then LaTeX only checks the second time, whether there are new options and throws the error, if new options are found. Is the `.log` file of the LaTeX run available on arxiv? It would probably tell the details of the option clash right after the error message and could give a hint, when `hyperref` is loaded the second time.

Answer (score 2):

Try include a file called `00README.XXX` with your submission containing the following contents:

```
nohypertex
```

This will [disable hyperref](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#nohypertex) which is included automatically (but with different options than called with the `tufte-handout` package).

### References

- [about 00README.XXX](https://arxiv.org/help/00README) (from the arXiv documentation)